# How do I make scrambled egg whites more like scrambled eggs?

Tags: eggs

Sometimes I scramble egg whites (or make an omelette) when I have a lot left over from using yolks for ice cream, and want to do something really quick to use the whites. I much prefer scrambled whole eggs - richer, less rubbery, and so on.

So, what can I do to make scrambled egg whites more like scrambled whole eggs?

Comment: How much ice cream are you making for this to be much of a concern? Just curious honestly. I yoke my eggs right over the sink with my hands. I just let the white go down the drain, but I am only using 3-5 yolks depending on the recipe.

Comment: Usually it's 4-6 whites depending on the recipe, sometimes I do two in a row and it's more. I wouldn't want to waste 3-5 whites either though! (And I do know other things to do with them too, this is mostly for the times when I want something really fast, and to get a breakfast out of it.)

Comment: Yeah I hear you...boy with that much yoke it's more like gelato huh?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not going to claim that I know a good answer to this question, and I hope perhaps other people can contribute other ideas.

I think this is a hard thing to find information on (particularly to obtain the "richer" element of whole eggs), partly because many people deliberately eat egg whites alone to save on calories.  But, like you, I sometimes end up with an excess of egg whites after baking or cooking something with a lot of yolks.

Slow cooking -- and most importantly, not overcooking -- seems to be a bigger issue than with whole eggs.  Otherwise, they end up tough.  I haven't tried it myself, but I've read that some people poach them instead (a "poach scramble") just to keep them tender and not overcooked.

But if you want to fry them as "normal" scrambled eggs, the only thing you can really do to improve them is add something else.  Here are a few things I've tried that might help:

- Mix in a whole egg per 1 to 3 egg whites.  It's not as rich or flavorful as all whole eggs, but it's more tolerable and has more of the standard "eggy" flavor.  I don't find a 1:1 mixture to be that bad at all.  Obviously the more you dilute it, the less it's like whole eggs.
- Add a dash or two of heavy cream (or other relatively rich dairy).  It will add back a little tenderness and richness.
- Add more butter than you'd usually use for whole scrambled eggs.  Same effect as above.
- If there are any herbs, vegetables, meats, cheese, or other ingredients you like in scrambled eggs or omelets, try adding some.  That can distract from the lack of flavor in the eggs themselves.